# Cannot Resolve the 'DatePickerFragment'

Tags: android, android-layout

When I tried to implement the date picker in android it showed me the following error.

> Cannot Resolve the 'DatePickerFragment'.

Can anyone help me to solve this? I am referring to [this](https://neurobin.org/docs/android/android-date-picker-example/) link and this screenshot

[image]

**datepick.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/datepick"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.fazils.datepicker.DatepickActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:text="Hai"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="pick_date"
    android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**DatepickActivity**

```
package com.example.fazils.datepicker;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
public class DatepickActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.datepick);
    }
    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you created DatePickerFragment in your project? It is a custom class not provided by Android SDK. You have to create it. Follow the link properly you shared.

Comment: u need to create a DatePickerFragment class first...

Comment: @nnn Thanks bro..

Answer (score 1):

You have no DatePickerFragment in your package and you have no import for it.

Answer (score 0):

add the below class in your package:

```
class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
         implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        TextView tv1= (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        tv1.setText("Year: "+view.getYear()+" Month: "+view.getMonth()+" Day: "+view.getDayOfMonth());

    }
}
```

**Source :** Your provided link